# cocoapods in building distribution profile

Tags: ios, swift, app-store, cocoapods

I used cocoapods in my app, and now I am building it to push in App Store with distribution profile, in manual they say that I need 2 files, but there are also cocoa pods archives, should I put them in archive for AppStore?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found solution, there are a lot of old guides, so it is easy to get wrong method of pushing app to App Store. Answer in this question - Xcode is archiving app by himself by Product -> Archive